# White Automation-

Tags: c#, winforms, white-framework

Having trouble having White open up a program and automate it to button click

```
{
        Application manager = Application.Launc(@"C:\\");
        Window mainWindow = manager.GetWindow("");

        Simulation(mainWindow);
        ZepSelect(mainWindow);

        manager.Kill();

    }
    //simulation mode
    private static void Simulation(Window mainWindow)
    {
        Window Sim = mainWindow.ModalWindow("");
        var searchCriteria = SearchCriteria.ByText("");
        var button = Sim.Get<Button>(searchCriteria);
        button.Click();
    }
//end simulation 
    private static void ZephyrSelect(Window mainWindow)
    {
        Window ZephOp = mainWindow.ModalWindow("");
        var searchCriteria1 = SearchCriteria.ByText("");
        var Zeph = ZephOp.Get<TreeNode>(searchCriteria1);
        Zephyr.Click();

        var searchCriteria2 = SearchCriteria.ByText("");
        var button = ZephOp.Get<Button>(searchCriteria2);
        button.Click();
    }
```

It runs but then I get the error when it reaches var button = Sim.Get(searchCriteria);  that object not set to an instance of an object. I'm observing that Sim is null. Any mistakes anyone can see that I'm making.

Comment: Please don't capitalize your variable names.  It's very confusing as that is intended to denote type names.

Comment: @KirkWoll Best practices are not ubiquitous rules. Not everyone agrees on the same naming and styling conventions.

Comment: yes for me I'm used to capitalizing  and it makes it clearer what the variables are declaring  but I do appreciate your input and I will keep it in mind

Comment: @KirkWoll I'm not saying I disagree. I'm just saying that his question is about a null reference, not about a peer review of coding style. I realize coding style is a very touchy subject, and I apologize if I touched a nerve.  @LewSim, have you tried providing a title when you call `mainWindow.ModelWindow("")`?

Comment: Yes there is a title in that command so I'm just not sure why I'm getting this error.